# React FB Tutorial-how parent component callback receives param order/values through child props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

Just ran through the official [thinking in react tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) from the facebook docs. 
Everything in the tutorial makes sense except for one point. I don't understand how FilterableProductTable's (parent component) callback function handleUserInput properly receives the order of it's parameters or how parameter values are passed into the callback function via SearchBar (child component) merely settings props in it's component function.

FilterableProductTable's callback function is:

```
handleUserInput: function(filterText, inStockOnly) {
  this.setState({
    filterText: filterText,
    inStockOnly: inStockOnly
  });
}
```

SearchBar setting's props component function:

```
handleChange: function() {
  this.props.onUserInput(
    this.refs.filterTextInput.value,
    this.refs.inStockOnlyInput.checked
  );
}
```

If you have never ran through the tutorial or didn't visit the github link above here is the finalized code from the tutorial:

```
var ProductCategoryRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<tr><th colSpan="2">{this.props.category}</th></tr>);
  }
});

var ProductRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var name = this.props.product.stocked ?
      this.props.product.name :
      <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {this.props.product.name}
      </span>;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
      if (product.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 || (!product.stocked && this.props.inStockOnly)) {
        return;
      }
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
      }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
      this.refs.filterTextInput.value,
      this.refs.inStockOnlyInput.checked
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={this.props.filterText}
          ref="filterTextInput"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.props.inStockOnly}
            ref="inStockOnlyInput"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          {' '}
          Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var FilterableProductTable = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      filterText: '',
      inStockOnly: false
    };
  },

  handleUserInput: function(filterText, inStockOnly) {
    this.setState({
      filterText: filterText,
      inStockOnly: inStockOnly
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
          onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
        />
        <ProductTable
          products={this.props.products}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: is your problem with how `refs` works in react?

Answer (score 0):

You see on `SearchBar` components `inputs` has an onchange handler 
`onChange={this.handleChange}`. Lets thake a look at the `handleChange` method.

```
handleChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
        this.refs.filterTextInput.value,
        this.refs.inStockOnlyInput.checked
    );
},
```

> The `handleChange` method then sends `onUserInput` the params in order

Answer (score 0):

The `handleUserInput` function is passed as a prop to the `SearchBar` through

```
   <SearchBar
      filterText={this.state.filterText}
      inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
      onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
    />
```

by the reference name `onUserInput`.

The following `onChange={this.handleChange}` in `SearchBar` calls the `handleChange function`
 In the searchbar onchange function i.e

```
handleChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
      this.refs.filterTextInput.value,
      this.refs.inStockOnlyInput.checked
    );
  },
```

You will see `SearchBar` `handleChange` function calling the `onUserInput` and passing parameters to it which indirectly means passing them to `handleUserInput` function.